# TFS 2013 Default Report Deploy

Tags: tfs, tfs-reports

My installation of TFS started with a basic install in TFS 2010. Since then it has been upgraded to 2012 and 2013 most recently. We have never modified the process templates. We use the MSF Agile templates. Again, they are the default templates. Recently, I added a report server to our deployment and wanted to deploy the default reports. I followed the instructions at the following page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn130125.aspx

I received the following error:

TF400587: This element defines the states for work items that appear on your backlog. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types belong to category defined in: 'RequirementBacklog/States'. The following state does not exist in any of the work item types: New.
The following element contains an error: TaskBacklog/States.
TF400587: This element defines the states for work items that appear on your backlog. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types belong to category defined in: 'TaskBacklog/States'. The following state does not exist in any of the work item types: New.

However, when I look in my ProcessConfiguration.xml and task.xml, New is there

```
<RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Stories" singularName="User Story">
    <States>
     <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
     <State value="Active" type="InProgress" />
     <State value="Resolved" type="InProgress" />
     <State value="Closed" type="Complete" />
    </States>
...
</RequirementBacklog>
```

and in the Task.xml

```
<WORKFLOW>
            <STATES>
                <STATE value="New">
                    <FIELDS>
                        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
                            <EMPTY />
                        </FIELD>
                        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
                            <EMPTY />
                        </FIELD>
                        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
                            <EMPTY />
                        </FIELD>
                        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
                            <EMPTY />
                        </FIELD>
                    </FIELDS>
                </STATE>
                <STATE value="Active">
                    <FIELDS>
                        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
                            <EMPTY />
                        </FIELD>
                        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
                            <EMPTY />
                        </FIELD>
                    </FIELDS>
                </STATE>
                <STATE value="Closed">
                    <FIELDS>
                        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
                            <REQUIRED />
                        </FIELD>
                    </FIELDS>
                </STATE>
                <STATE value="Removed" />
            </STATES>
...
</WORKFLOW>
```

and in User Story.xml

```
<WORKFLOW>
      <STATES>
        <STATE value="New">
            <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
                <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
                <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
                <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
                <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
                <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
                <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            </FIELDS>
        </STATE>
        <STATE value="Active">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </STATE>
        <STATE value="Resolved">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </STATE>
    <STATE value="Closed" />
    <STATE value="Removed" />
  </STATES>
```

This happens when I run the following command to deploy the reports

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools>tfpt addprojectreports /collection:"http://tfs_location:8080/tfs/group" /teamproject:"project /processtemplate:"MSF for Agile Software Development 2013"
```

As far as I know, there are no updates to TFS or SQL that I am missing. I see no errors in the server log.

My question is, how do I fix this?  I haven't done any modifications and I need teh default reports.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lakhminder/archive/2010/09/30/create-tfs-2010-reports-for-upgraded-team-projects.aspx

I get "Parameter name: valueValue cannot be null."

Update:

Here's a snippet from Categories.xml

```
  <CATEGORY name="Requirement Category" refname="Microsoft.RequirementCategory">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="User Story" />
  </CATEGORY>  
<CATEGORY name="Task Category" refname="Microsoft.TaskCategory">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Task" />
  </CATEGORY>
```

Comment: Did you run the "Configure Feature" wizard after you went from TFS2010 to 2012? Go to http://[server]/[CollectionName]/[ProjectName]/_admin

Comment: What is in your Categories.xml.  Is User Story assigned to the RequirementsCategory?

Comment: Posted the relevant snippet from Categories.xml.  I did configure the new features when we did 2012.  There's nothing left to configure at this point.

Comment: I'm confused, do you get the error about the states, or do you get the Paramater name error?  Setting up reports shouldn't care about state mappings in the backlogs.

Comment: I agree, it's confusing.  Why is it complaining about mappings when it's supposed to be uploading reports.  I get the error that I posted complaining about the "New" state not existing in teh work item types

Comment: The parameter value error was trying a different method of uploading the default templates by using File.BatchNewTEamProject method approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to setup your Categories appropriately.  You need to ensure that your User Story Work Item Type is included in the Requirements Category.

You can download (or upload) the Categories.xml file using witadmin.exe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd273721.aspx

Comment: The task is in the task category and the user story is in teh requirements category.  I literally downloaded the default and re-uploaded just to make sure it was setup properly

Comment: But you said you upgraded from TFS 2010.  The 2010 default template, even upgraded all the way to 2013, is not the same as the default 2013 template.

Comment: Okay.  I can't see anything wrong with my config.  I put a snippet in the main post.

Comment: You were right.  It wasn't my categories.xml.  It was my user story and task definition.  Even though the template on TFS had those fields, the team project didn't have it.  I thought it was applied with teh 2012 update when I configured new features.